Way to show the beta-function identity $(p+z)B(p,z+1)=zB(p,z)$ "directly"
The beta-function $B(p,q)$ satisfies the identity
$$(p+z)B(p,z+1)=zB(p,z).$$
This can be shown easily via the identity
$$B(p,q) = \frac{\Gamma(p)\Gamma(q)}{\Gamma(p+q)}$$
and that $\Gamma(z+1) = z\Gamma(z)$, which causes the $(p+z)$ factor to disappear and the $z$ factor to appear.
I wonder though if it is possible to show directly via the integral
$$B(p,q) = \int_0^1 t^{p-1} (1-t)^{q-1} dt.$$
I've tried writing $(p+z)B(p,z+1) = (p+z)\int_0^1 t^{p-1} (1-t)^{z} dt$ and performing integration by parts, but that does not work as we get a factor of $B(p\color{red}{+1},z)$, i.e. swapping the location of the $+1$.
Is it possible to do this, this way?

Similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208925/how-can-i-get-bx-y1-fracyxy-bx-y-using-integration-by-parts

\begin{eqnarray*}
B(p,z+1) &=& \int_0^1 t^{p-1} (1-t)(1-t)^{z-1} dt \\
&=& \int_0^1\left[ t^{p-1}(1-t)^{z-1}-t^{p}(1-t)^{z-1} \right]dt\\
&=& \int_0^1 t^{p-1}(1-t)^{z-1}dt-\int_{0}^1t^{p}(1-t)^{z-1} dt\\
&=& B(p,z)-B(p+1,z)
\end{eqnarray*}
On the other hand,
\begin{eqnarray*}
B(p,z+1)&=& \int_0^1t^{p-1}(1-t)^{z}dt\\
&=& \left[\frac{t^p(1-t)^z}{p}\right]_0^1+\frac{z}{p}\int_0^1t^{p}(1-t)^{z-1}dt\\
&=& \frac{z}{p}B(p+1,z)
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence
$$ B(p,z+1) = B(p,z) -\frac{p}{z}B(p,z+1)\implies \frac{z+p}{z}B(p,z+1) = B(p,z)$$
Another proof:
\begin{eqnarray*}
B(p,z+1) &=& \int_0^1 t^{p+z-1}\left(\frac{1-t}{t}\right)^z dt\\
&=& \left[\frac{t^{p+z}}{p+z}\left(\frac{1-t}{t}\right)\right]_0^1 + \frac{z}{p+z} \int_0^1 t^{p-1}(1-t)^{z-1}dt \\
&=& \frac{z}{p+z}B(p,z)
\end{eqnarray*}
